# Query string always returns NULL on Server side

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, tomcat, jersey

I'm having some trouble creating an API for a project.

My issue is the following:

On the client side, I have a `Javascript` file with a GET request to my server side.

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function() {
    $("#snipList").empty();
    var search = $("#tagSearch").val();
    var send = "http://localhost:8081/OhSnip/api/snippets/" + search;
    $.getJSON(send, function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);       
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            console.log(value.nome_snippet);
            $("#snipList").append("<div class='snippet'><h1>" + value.nome_snippet + "</h1><br><h3>" + value.classificacao + "/5</h3>");
        });
    });
});
```

And I need to send the content of a textbox to the Server side.

On the server side, I have this

```
@Path("/snippets")
public class Resource {

    @Path("/{search}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Snippet> getSearch(@QueryParam("search") String search) {
        System.out.println(search);
        SnippetManager SM = SnippetManager.getInstance();       
        if (search!=null) {
            return SM.getSnippets(search);
        } else {
            return SM.getSnippets();
        }   
    }
}
```

I have no clue why the search query always returns null.

My JavaScript code worked on most APIs I've used but this is the first time I'm having lots of issues.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure your frontend actually adds some value?

Comment: If you expect a query parameter would that not have to be `"http://localhost:8081/OhSnip/api/snippets?search=" + search;` or similar?

Comment: You're not sending any querystring value...

Answer (score 1):

Your `search` parameter is a path parameter, not a query parameter .

Consider replacing `@QueryParam` with `@PathParam` .

Answer (score 0):

`@QueryParam` can extract query parameter from the Query component of the request URL if the query parameter is not present in the request then the value will be an empty collection forList.

Actually, your `search` parameter is a path parameter so you need replacing `@QueryParam` with `@PathParam`.

I suggest you look at the documentation: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html